# Minecraft /playsound for raid horn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried `/playsound ominous_horn_blares` and it did not work. How can I play the raid horn sound? in minecraft with `/playsound`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `/playsound minecraft:event.raid.horn hostile @a ~ ~ ~ 1`. The 1 at the end is the volume, so if you can't hear it, turn it up. Personally, I could hear it at volume 100, and pretty well at 1000.

For more information on the command, here is the [`/playsound`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/playsound) wiki.
For more information on sounds, here are all of the [Java Edition sounds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json#Java_Edition_values).

**Edit:**

For bedrock users, the [`/playsound`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/playsound) wiki applies too, but as described in the site, the syntax is a little different. I don't have BE, so I can't test it, but I think the command should be `/playsound raid.horn @a ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1`. The first 1 is the volume, the next is the pitch, and the last is the minimum volume.

The full list of bedrock sounds can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json#Bedrock_Edition_values). Make sure to click `[show]` on the page to expand the list.

Comment: I hate all this event.raid or this.that mumbo jumbo. I wish is was just playsound minecraft:horn or something

Comment: Yeah for obscure things it's easier that way, but when you look at the amount of sound files there are, having them grouped by source, so for example `minecraft:entity.skeleton.something`, it's easier to manage overall.

Comment: @Julian Plus, Minecraft is really nice in that the wikis are kept pretty well maintained, especially for things like commands, nbt, and such, so it's pretty easy to find things like sounds once you figure out how it works. Granted, figuring that out in the first place is really hard, so there's ups and downs.

Comment: I'm playing on bedrock and I tried out the command with no luck is there a way I could do this on bedrock.

Comment: @RetryVx Sorry for the *very* late response, but I just edited it to provide information for BE.